# How to synchronize two task using semaphore in VxWorks?

Tags: c, semaphore, vxworks

How can I synchronize two tasks using binary semaphores in VxWorks 6.9.?

I want output to be like:

> a A b B c C .... z Z

How can I do that?

**test.c**

```
#include <taskLib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <kernelLib.h>
#include <semLib.h> 
SEM_ID t1,t2;
int task(void)
{
    char i;
    for(i='a';i<='z';i++)
    {   
    //    semTake(t1,WAIT_FOREVER);
    //    semTake(t2,WAIT_FOREVER);
          printf("%c ",i);
    //    semGive(t2);
    }  
}
int task2(void)
{
    char i;
    for(i='A';i<='Z';i++)
    {       
    //    semTake(t2,WAIT_FOREVER);
    //    semTake(t1,WAIT_FOREVER);
          printf("%c ",i);  
    //    semGive(t1);
    }
}
void Main(void)
{
    int id1,id2;
    t1= semBCreate(SEM_Q_PRIORITY, SEM_EMPTY);
    t2 = semBCreate(SEM_Q_PRIORITY, SEM_EMPTY);
    id1=taskSpawn("First",120,0,1000,(FUNCPTR) task, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0);
    id2=taskSpawn("Second",120,0,1000,(FUNCPTR) task2, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0);      
}
```

Comment: You need a barrier semaphore. This semaphore synchronizes each thread at a given point, In this case it is the end of your for loop.

Comment: I didn't get you @Nishant. can u edit my code..?

Comment: and more thing is i commented some portion. why this not working ? any specific reason @Nishant

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have access to VxWorks so I can not edit your code.
About the commented code, consider that `task` acquires `t1` and the gets context switched out before acquiring `t2`. Then `task2` is scheduled and it acquires `t2`and waits on `t1`. Now `task` gets scheduled but it will wait on `t2`. So, none of `task` and `task2` can proceed as they are waiting on semaphore acquired by the other one. A classic deadlock :) Try to look up barrier semaphore on the internet.

Comment: If you create both semaphores empty, and then try to wait on them as the first action/s of your threads, then nothing useful is going to happen.  You need to throw in one 'token' unit that the threads then swap around using the two semaphores.

Comment: Thanks @Nishant, Yes, in my scenario I was getting deadlock. let me thing new about it.

Comment: @MartinJames can u explain in code... I didn't get u.

Answer (score 0):

You should  create  t1 with SEM_FULL option in order to have "first" task execute first. Then first task should take t1 and give t2; second task take t2 and give t1.